# Remove Redundant fields in two associated Mongoid Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, class, mongoid, omniauth

In my `omniauth` & `omniauth-identity` based app I came across the follwoing issue:

There are three tables that manage Userdata:

```
# Stores User data _not_ authentication data
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :identities
  field :email, type: String
end

# Stores Authentication data (i.e. Facebook)
class Identity
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :user
end

# Stores Authentication data for omniauth-identity
class LocalIdentity < Identity
  include OmniAuth::Identity::Models::Mongoid

  field :email, type: String
end
```

The issue is now that I have duplicated the email-field in `LocalIdentity`. So whenever a user changes his email-address in the `User` model I need to synchronize the email address. This seems trivial at first but can get real messy as soon as there are more fields involved etc.

So my question is: Is there a way to remove the redundance between `User` and `LocalIdentity`?

While pondering about a solution i came to the following conclusions:

- Multi Inheritance isn't supported so `LocalIdentity < Identity, User` won't work
- Having a `LocalIdentity` embedded in every `User` and
  write-trough the values won't work b/c validations wouldn't work

Comment: Have you tried to delegate the field with `delegate :email, :to => :user` instead of having its own field in `LocalIdentity`?

Comment: Ill try that, didn't know delegate existed